Please welcome The Nineteenth Byte's newest room owners (2024)!
Voting has closed, and five out of six candidates have surpassed the vote threshold (≥ 10 upvotes, at least 3× upvotes vs. downvotes) and have been elected as room owners for CGCC's main chat room, The Nineteenth Byte:





They have been appointed, effective immediately. Please welcome them as our new room owners and join us in thanking them for volunteering!
In the words of Dennis, caird coinheringaahing, and me, may the odds be ever in their favor.

Congrats to all of y'all! I have full confidence in everyone who was voted to the position of RO. I do have a few warnings, though:

With great power comes great responsibility. You now have the ability to (checks notes) pin messages, update feeds, and create cosmic paradoxes.
You MUST change "messages" to something silly when moving spam to trash and/or the bakery. This is non-negotiable.
Don't accidentally move stuff to DBA's main chat room (oops)
If you kick-mute too many times a swarm of mods will be summoned, tens of thousands clad all in sable armor and bristling with swords and spears
We all agree it would be funny if TNB was called The Nineteenth Bingus but please don't rename it (I have no idea what would happen but it would be bad[TM])
Chat isn't about the destination, it's about the bugs we encountered along the way
NP and SP aren't regular feeds. If they do a silly (or don't do a silly when one is requisite), please contact me angrily
You'll probably forget you don't have RO powers in some other room on the network at some point and try to do an RO action, and even if you thought nobody was watching, someone was, and they're laughing very hard at you specifically
Butter is the fuel on which the bots run. Keeping it in stock is most of what the job consists of.
You're now objectively trusted and respected by the community of chat, and CGCC as a whole, and you definitely deserve it


A note on point 2: make sure to leave some NP spam messages for me so I can 11 them into funny messages about butter :p

I've been doing point 2 forever in TGC lol

@lyxal But does NP = P?

Haha italic names go brrr.
What? What do you mean I've said that before?
Well in that case, I have the fullest confidence that the new ROs will do an excellent job keeping the main room of the code golf tame!

Woah. That's certainly something to come back to after 24 days of being off the internet!
Thanks for entrusting me with the silly funny goofy room owner tools of TNB. I vow to use the tools for good! (Does that sound cool enough?)
Oh also I accept, yes I accept, definitely :P

Mwahahahaha! My operation to dominate every site main chatroom is one step closer to— er, I mean, I promise not to move messages to DBA by accident? Also, I have a warehouse full of butter here somewhere...

I'm happy to be elected! Thank you all for entrusting me with this responsibility, and I promise I will always check twice before clicking Move Messages :p

Too bad I didn’t get elected, but GG to those who did! 
